# Text word-wrapping in <li>

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, html-lists, responsive

In my `<li></li>` The words are wrapping towards underneath the bullet points instead of wrapping down underneath the first letter of the sentence.

I was able to achieve centering my bullet points to the center of my page and having the text to be left-aligned. Now I want my words to wrap underneath the first letter of the sentence and not go left beyond the first letter towards the bullet points.

This is all happening when I resized it down to mobile size.

[image: list weird]

```css
.plans {
  text-align: center;
}

.plans ul {
  display: inline-block;
  list-style-position: inside;
  text-align: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="plans">

  <h2>In magna dolor enim id reprehenderit sint magna in.</h2>

  <ul>
    <li>Do anim aliqua veniam ullamco proident</li>
    <li>Magna ex in reprehenderit ut officia in do aliqua ut.</li>
    <li><strong>Do dolore cupidatat</strong> nostrud do anim adipisicing nostrud et dolore sed excepteur.</li>
    <li><strong>Duis nulla aliqua</strong> esse adipisicing et officia reprehenderit.</li>
  </ul>list

</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`list-style-position`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/list-style-position) to change how the bullet point is positioned- `outside` is what you're looking for in this case

```css
.plans {
  text-align: center;
  width: 500px;
}

.plans ul {
  display: inline-block;
  list-style-position: outside;
  text-align: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="plans">

  <h2>In magna dolor enim id reprehenderit sint magna in.</h2>

  <ul>
    <li>Do anim aliqua veniam ullamco proident</li>
    <li>Magna ex in reprehenderit ut officia in do aliqua ut.</li>
    <li><strong>Do dolore cupidatat</strong> nostrud do anim adipisicing nostrud et dolore sed excepteur.</li>
    <li><strong>Duis nulla aliqua</strong> esse adipisicing et officia reprehenderit.</li>
  </ul>

</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! Just changed my list-style-position from inside to outside and that fixed my issue!

Answer (score 0):

Use `list-style-position: outside;` instead of `inside`. Try this:

```css
.plans {
  text-align: center;
}

.plans ul {
  display: inline-block;
  list-style-position: outside;
  text-align: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="plans">

  <h2>In magna dolor enim id reprehenderit sint magna in.</h2>

  <ul>
    <li>Do anim aliqua veniam ullamco proident</li>
    <li>Magna ex in reprehenderit ut officia in do aliqua ut.</li>
    <li><strong>Do dolore cupidatat</strong> nostrud do anim adipisicing nostrud et dolore sed excepteur.</li>
    <li><strong>Duis nulla aliqua</strong> esse adipisicing et officia reprehenderit.</li>
  </ul>

</div>
```